# Generate kibana iframes (short url) dynamically

Tags: jquery, node.js, elasticsearch, iframe, kibana

I have a webpage which has a select dropdown with some months as it's options, and a div with kibana iframe. Whenever user selects a month from dropdown, the UI should be able to change the iframe visualization to that of selected month. I have written a simple code which simply changes the iframe source whenever month is changed. I now want to be able to get these iframe links(url) from Nodejs server or Kibana.

```
<select id="month">
    <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
    <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
    <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
    <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
</select>

<div>
    <iframe id="monthVisualization"></iframe>
</div>

/*function that is executed when month is selected from dropdown*/
function changeIframe(month)    {
    /*some code that gets iframe link of visualization of month that is received as parameter*/
    var url = someLink;
    $('#monthVisualization').attr('src', someLink);
}
```

Note: The dropdown keeps changing its options, as it is dynamically generated. How do I create and access iframes (with short url) that are generated dynamically based on these options? (I don't want manual creation of iframes at kibana by any person, it should be generated automatically)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you have a look on the [kibana API](https://github.com/Webiks/kibana-API) plugin